# How to delete all data when uninstalling a ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application in C#, and I want to uninstall all files during an automatic uninstall.

Previously I've used the following to return my Application Data Path :

```
static public string APPLICATION_DATA_PATH
{
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).ToString(), "myFolder\\");
        }
}
```

This returns `c://Users/UserName/AppData/MyFolder` which works but, with automatic uninstall of a ClickOnce application, this folder isn't deleted.

Now, I test with :

```
static public string APPLICATION_DATA_PATH
{
    get
    {
        if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            // If Clickonce Application is deployed.
            return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
        } 
        else
        {
            // If I'm in debug mode (with visual studio)
            return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).ToString(), "myFolder\\");
        }
    }
}
```

That works with Visual Studio debugging but, when I publish my application, and I install on any computer, my application crashes and the Windows Report (WER) just says "APPLICATION CRASH".

I've got no idea why my this doesn't work if my APPLICATION_DATA_PATH is correct...

Have you any idea for debugging a ClickOnce application using `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` path? Or an idea for removing all files with ClickOnce uninstaller?

**EDIT**

I arrived to debug my ClickOnce Application (thx @JRoughan for help),
Now, I saw My "APPLICATION_PATH" return null, I've change my code :

```
static public string APPLICATION_DATA_PATH
    {
        get
        {
            string path = null;                
            if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                path = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;
            }

            return path;
        }
    }
```

If null is return, Code don't approuved the "System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed", but why? I've install a new clickonce application... and the application is deployed, the code should return the "CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory"! no ?

**FINAL EDIT**

Finally, the path works correctly.
On the start of my application, I restart here, if application don't have the administrator rules, but, when Clickonce Application have Administrator rules, the path don't work...
Thanks for help!

Comment: I think the trailing backslash might have something to do with it.

Comment: @JRoughan when suggesting an edit please try to fix all issues of the post at once, so that you don't need to suggest two edits on the same post.

Comment: @Spontifixus I edited it again because it was still so hard to look at. Why are you discouraging improvements? Do you think I'm trying to game the system for 2 points?

Comment: @JRoughan I don't discourage improvements. It's just that the review workload for >2k Members is rather high. You have a preview of the post at hand when editing. So just try to fix *all* issues in one edit suggestion. Look at the post twice before submitting the suggestion. Ensure you have missed nothing. (And no I'm not thinking you try to game the system. Contrary to "Gamers" you did actually improve the post with each of your suggestions, otherwise I would have rejected them.)

Comment: @Spontifixus Duly noted and ignored, sorry. Your statement equates to "please don't ever make mistakes or miss anything". If I miss something in future I will do exactly what I did here; if the review workload is too high for the number of reviewers then *that's* the problem, not the people trying to improve things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to debug an installed ClickOnce application so you can see exactly what's happening you should be able to attach the debugger to the process using the VS menu 'Debug -> Attach to Process'. Make sure the right solution is loaded first.

If you're just asking why the data directory isn't being cleaned correctly, I'm not sure; This folder should follow the lifetime of the ClickOnce install and be cleaned up during uninstall.

Is it possible you're loading resources from this folder and not releasing them so they're locked and undeletable at the time of uninstall?

Comment: I don't know, I've two error on my application, this ( System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory, don't works [ when I start my clickonce application, this application crash...] ) and other, when I uninstall my clickonce application, uninstaller don't kill my application process) Maybe two errors are linked? 

I look your solution for "attach a process" in debugger. Thx

Comment: Hi, I don't try to attached a process, My Clickonce publish Crash when I start application, and, process was kill with the crash :'( Thanks for idea.

Comment: Could you try putting a `Thread.Sleep()` right at the start of the app to give you time to attach? How soon does it crash? Even better would be adding a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` on the first line in `Main` and choosing your existing VS instance to debug.

Comment: Hi, gg, your method work for atach the process. And I saw it's not the "System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirect‌​ory" that crash my Application...

For enable all priviligie I restart my application in "runas" but my application do not restart....

When I use the old path ( folder in appData ) that works, when i use the clickOnce DataDirectory... application can't restart...

Comment: Can you please update your original question with more details? Why can't it restart? Does nothing happen? Is an exception thrown (and if so which one and what's the message)?

Comment: Hi, I mark resolved your post, because, this is the one who helped me the most. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in ClickOnce deployment to perform any kind of tasks when you uninstall the application. In theory, the ClickOnce scavenger will come around eventually and take care of the files, but I find this to be unreliable. Basically, there's nothing you can do about this short of installing and running a program to clear the \apps\2.0\data\whatever folder in question.